# Apex 4.2 capture filepath using file browse item

Tags: oracle-apex

Apex 4.2 : I want to capture the filepath after browsing and selecting a file  using item File browse (WWV_FLOW_FILES). The file is uploaded as a BLOB but all info regarding its original location is missing, as it is replaced by f.i. `F12457/<name doc>.docx`.  When using File Browse (browsing for a document and selecting) however the complete path (f.i. L:\abc\def\document.docx) is shown in the field (although its value then is already F999999/document.docx).

Answer (score 1):

Browser security stops JavaScript from accessing this information

[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

eg:

```
$('#P6_FILE').val()

"C:\fakepath\12c_notes.txt"
```

Comment: What if I want to capture file name at runtime?

Comment: To what end? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: $('#P6_FILE').val()match(/\\([^\\]*)$/)[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
v_doc varchar2(100);
begin
select :P_DOCUMENT into v_doc from dual;
:P59_DOCNAME := v_doc;
end;
```